# Zend Framework 2 Routing: Automatically redirect to sub-route

Tags: zend-framework2

Let's take the example routing config from the documentation (slightly modified):

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
                        'action' => 'index'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'blog' => array(
                'type' => 'literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/blog',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Applicaton\Controller\BlogController',
                        'action' => 'index'
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'rss' => array(
                        'type' => 'literal',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/rss',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'action' => 'rss'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
                // ... other child routes ...
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I want to automatically do a redirect to `/blog/rss` whenever `/blog` is called.

Right now I have to redirect from within the index-action of BlogController. I wonder if there is a way to let ZF2 handle the redirect without writing additional code in the action?

Comment: I don't think you can redirect like that using the router, you could make your own router to do this ;)

Comment: How about `'action' => 'rss'` on the `/blog` route? Why think so complicated when just it is so very easy?

Comment: @Sam, you would get duplicate content this way because the same page is available on /blog and /blog/css.

Comment: Try with may_terminate => false

Comment: Why not using mod_rewrite for doing that redirect?